# How do I write a method that has the same implementation for multiple kinds of objects (Java)?

Tags: java, interface

I am writing a (currently) String-based Pokemon game in Java. With the structure I have, there are currently 2 kinds of objects that I want to do Type matchups for: Pokemon and moves. The method I want to write (isStrongAgainst()) would be the same for both. For example, a water type pokemon and a water type move are strong against fire type Pokemon, but these comparisons can imply different things based on context. Both classes have differently implemented isType() methods.

The idea I had was to use an interface that implements a default isStrongAgainst() method and declares an abstract isType() method. I would think that since any class that implements this interface would have to implement isType(), I could use it in my isStrongAgainst(), but I cannot. Is there any way around this or a better suggestion given my problem?

```
public interface TypeMatch<T> {
    boolean isType(Type t);
    default boolean isStrongAgainst(Pokemon opponent){
        if(T.isType(Type.NORMAL)){
            return false;
        }
        if(T.isType(Type.WATER)){
            return opponent.isType(Type.FIRE) ||
                    opponent.isType(Type.ROCK) ||
                    opponent.isType(Type.GROUND);
        } //etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as understand, your game contains different behaviors according to type of a Pokemon. I highly recommend you to use [strategy design pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm).

Comment: Hello Orkun. This could've been a comment. Avoid giving one line answers as it doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is that the `isStrongAgainst()` function can be refined more. 
It would better to make an implementation of `isType()` in such a way that it returns `true` if the opponent is weaker than us.

This can then be used in the function `isStrongAgainst()` directly in its return statement.

Best

*PS:* I am in class right now and I will give a more detailed answer after I’m over with it, till then if possible try to get some idea of what I have said.

Answer (score 0):

You may:

1. define Pokemon as an abstract class to implement TypeMatch
2. move isStrongAgainst(Pokemon opponent) from TypeMatch to Pokemon.
3. any class that extends Pokemon has the same implementation of isStrongAgainst(Pokemon opponent)